# How to refer Material Design 3 - Tokens/Colors in Android XML

Tags: android, material-design

I'm new to `Material Design 3`. I'm trying to understand and use in `Android Views (XML)`. I want to build the design with `DynamicColors` Referring to the following image: [image]

I am unable to understand how can I use **Design Tokens** e.g., Surface container md.sys.color.surface-container in `Android XML` to use as a `background` color. My basic design theme file is as follows:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.BasicM3App" parent="Theme.Material3.DynamicColors.DayNight">
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.BasicM3App" parent="Base.Theme.BasicM3App" />
</resources>
```

and my **Layout** file where I want to use **colorSurface** as the background color:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="" <<<======== Here I want to use colorSurface for dynamic behavior
            android:layout_weight="1">
```

Comment: Did you find a way